# What does var mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to know what the code `var` means and what the code  `var focusname=""`  and `var msg=" ";` does and what its use is, its part of my assessment and i need to know i am allowed to use help, i am very new to HTML.

Any help would be very appreciated

```
    <title>Exam entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
window.validateForm=function() {
    var result = true;
    var msg = "";
    var focusname="";
    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {
        msg += "You must enter your name \n";
        focusname="name";
        //document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }
    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == "") {
        msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
       // document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="subject";
        }
        document.getElementById('subject1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }
    var Number = document.ExamEntry.Exam_Number.value
    if (Number == "") {
        msg += "You must enter the exam Number \n";
        //document.ExamEntry.Exam_Number.focus();
        if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="Exam_Number";
        }
        document.getElementById('Exam_Number1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }else if (Number.length != 4) {
        msg += "You must enter at least Four Numbers in the Exam Number \n";
         if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="Exam_Number";
        }
        //document.ExamEntry.Exam_Number.focus();
        document.getElementById('Exam_Number1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }
else if (isNaN(Number)) {
        msg += "You must enter at least four numeric characters in the Exam Number feild \n";
     if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="Exam_Number";
        }   
    // document.ExamEntry.Exam_Number.focus();
        document.getElementById('Exam_Number1').style.color = "red";
        //result = false;
    }
    var valchecked = '';
    var len = document.getElementsByName('examtype').length;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

if ( document.ExamEntry.examtype[i].checked ) {

valchecked = document.ExamEntry.examtype[i].value;
 break;

}

}
    if (valchecked == '') {
        msg += "Select Exam Type";
        document.getElementById('Exam_Type').style.color = "red";
         if (focusname=="")
        {
        focusname="examtype_GCSE";
        }

    } 

    if (msg != ""){
        alert(msg)
        document.getElementById(focusname).focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        return confirm('You have chosen ' + valchecked + ' is this correct?');
    }

}
}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="name1">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name"  id="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="subject1">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Exam_Number1">Exam Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Exam_Number" id="Exam_Number" ><font size="3">(Maximum characters: 4)</font> </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<table><form action="">
<td id="Exam_Type">Exam Type</td>
<tr><td><input type="radio" id="examtype_GCSE" name="examtype" value="GCSE" /> : GCSE<br /></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" id="examtype_AS" name="examtype" value="AS"/> : AS<br /></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" id="examtype_A2" name="examtype" value="A2" /> : A2<br /></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You're "very new" to Javascript, but did you even read just a little bit about it? Variable declaration is not an advanced concept. MDN is a good resource for this type of question: [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: You obviously have not even bothered to do any research prior to asking this here. www.we3schools.com is a very useful resource for Javascript and programming in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` is used to declare the variable in javascript.

`var msg="";` means you declared the variable `msg` which is empty and same with the `focusname`.

For more info about [**var**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 0):

Variables are declared with the var keyword as follows:

Ex- `var msg; //multi line declaration
     var focusname;`

```
var msg, focusname; //Single line declaration
```

Here, msg & focusname are variable names that holds value.

var keyword is used only for declaration.

JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. This means that a JavaScript variable can hold a value of any data type.

Unlike many other languages, you don't have to tell JavaScript during variable declaration what type of value the variable will hold. 
The value type of a variable can change during the execution of a program and JavaScript takes care of it automatically.

Comment: Saying that JavaScript is "untyped" isn't true. It uses dynamic typing, but it has types. There is even a [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator.